# Angular App data-binding with undefined child objects elvis operator or custom interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I am working in a large angular 6 app, and we recently had a data integrity issue from our APIs, and this broke our site.

We are data-binding the following:
{{parent.child1.child2}}

The api was returning the parent but not child1 or child2. So this broke our site.

I was curious what the best practice was for handling this?

One solution was using the elvis operator: {{parent?.child1?.child2}}
The other was to create an interface, and use some custom validator for the API's response.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `&&` operator for achieving this as well.

For example you can use the expression`{{parent&&parent.child1&&parent.child1.child2}}`. 
It will return `parent.child1.child2` if both `parent` and `parent.child1` are truthy and objects are truthy so it will work fine in your case.